# how to call a module file in header file in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: php

I have a module of facebook login.

But it could be add in content top or content bottom I want to add it in header for users.

Could someone can tell me how to call a module named `facebook_login.tpl` as

```
 <?php $facebook_login ?> in header.tpl file in Opencart 2.0.1.1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will call controller in header.php file. for eg. if you want to call controller of facebook_login.php file so you need to write code in header.php like :

```
$data['facebook_login'] = $this->load->controller('common/facebook_login');
```

and in header.tpl file you need to write code like :

```
<?php echo $facebook_login;?>
```

maybe it will be helpful

Thanks